Relations of has many causes panic in armv7 device
The same code can run normally on my computer (x86 windows) and device (armv7 Linux) without using a one to many relationship. Once a one to many relationship is used, it can run normally on my computer (x86 Windows). But when my device (armv7 Linux) is running, it will cause a panic.

Objectbox version: objectbox-go v1.8.0

Objectbox lib version: libobjectbox.so v4.0.1

Device: x86 Windows and armv7 Linux

Reproducibility: always


main.go:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox"
    "objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model"
)

func initObjectBox() *objectbox.ObjectBox {
    objectBox, err := objectbox.NewBuilder().Model(model.ObjectBoxModel()).Directory("./opt").Build()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return objectBox
}

func main() {
    // load objectbox
    ob := initObjectBox()
    defer ob.Close() // In a server app, you would just keep ob and close on shutdown
    box := model.BoxForTask(ob)
    box2 := model.BoxForWorkers(ob)
    if box == nil || box2 == nil {
        panic("box ini fail")
    }
    worker1 := model.Workers{Name: "Petter", Age: 18}
    worker2 := model.Workers{Name: "Leven", Age: 28}
    workers := []*model.Workers{&worker1, &worker2}
    id, _ := box.Put(&model.Task{
        Text:    "Buy milk",
        Workers: workers,
    })
    tasks, err := box.Get(id) // panic.......
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("read err ", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(tasks)
}

model/task.go:
package model

//go:generate go run github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/cmd/objectbox-gogen

// Put this on a new line to enable sync: // `objectbox:"sync"`
type Task struct {
    Id           uint64
    Text         string
    Name         string
    DataType     string
    Value        float64
    ValueStr     string
    DateCreated  int64
    DateFinished int64
    Workers      []*Workers
}

type Workers struct {
    Id   uint64
    Name string
    Age  int
}

Windows Log: &{6 Buy milk   0  0 0 [0xc000086020 0xc000086040]}
Linux (ARMV7) Log:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x13d6c8]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.dataVisitorDispatch(0xb55f17b0, 0x40, 0x4137c0)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/datavisitorc.go:43 +0x50
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox._Cfunc_obx_box_visit_many(0x2cdff0, 0x2ce078, 0x142d4c, 0x4137c0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:745 +0x38
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).GetManyExisting.func2.1(0x5147b0, 0x5147e0, 0x4137c0)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:531 +0xc8
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).GetManyExisting.func2(0x4137c0)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:531 +0x70
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).readUsingVisitor.func2.1()
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:621 +0x24
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.cCall(0x4d7cf4)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/c-tools.go:34 +0x20
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).readUsingVisitor.func2()
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:621 +0x4c
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*ObjectBox).runInTxn(0x505860, 0x1, 0x4d7d64)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/objectbox.go:155 +0xcc
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*ObjectBox).RunInReadTx(...)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/objectbox.go:110
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).readUsingVisitor(0x5147b0, 0x1, 0x4d7da0)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:620 +0x27c
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).GetManyExisting(0x5147b0, {0x4137b0, 0x2, 0x2})
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:533 +0x158
objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model.(*WorkersBox).GetManyExisting(...)
    /mnt/d/gitlab/tools/objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model/task.obx.go:617
objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model.task_EntityInfo.Load({{0x1}, 0x284bb4920ec6bdbe}, 0x505860, {0xb55f1680, 0x80, 0x80})
    /mnt/d/gitlab/tools/objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model/task.obx.go:170 +0x144
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).Get.func1()
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:479 +0x18c
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*ObjectBox).runInTxn(0x505860, 0x1, 0x4d7f10)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/objectbox.go:155 +0xcc
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*ObjectBox).RunInReadTx(...)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/objectbox.go:110
github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/objectbox.(*Box).Get(0x514790, 0x3)
    /home/lich/go/pkg/mod/github.com/levin-go/objectbox-go@v0.0.0-20240826085105-f32fc4305353/objectbox/box.go:470 +0x80
objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model.(*TaskBox).Get(0x4d7f90, 0x3)
    /mnt/d/gitlab/tools/objectboxTest/objectboxlib/model/task.obx.go:258 +0x30
main.main()
    /mnt/d/gitlab/tools/objectboxTest/main.go:34 +0x198


I'm seeing that you already created a bug report at the appropriate place: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/issues/52 - I think it should be closed on SO.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a bug report.
